# Plotting Fresnel function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I am trying to plot the partial sums and the Cesàro means of the function $\sqrt{|x|}$ and for $a_{n}$, I obtained the following code which contains `FresnelS`.

```
(-((Sqrt[2] FresnelS[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n]])/n^(3/2)) - (Sqrt[2] FresnelS[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Abs[n]]])/Abs[n]^(3/2) + (2 Sin[n π])/n + (2 Sin[π Abs[n]])/Abs[n])/(2 Sqrt[π])
```

Now my question is, is it possible to graph such a function using *Mathematica*? I have tried many examples using trial and error and some of the my examples also contain `BesselJ` which can't be graphed.

Hence, I would like to know if it is true that if there is `BesselJ` and `FresnelS` in the code, then the graph cannot be drawn using *Mathematica*. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am graphing out its graph using this code:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[Abs[Mod[x, 2 Pi, -Pi]]];
s[k_, x_] := ???
partialsums[x_] = Table[s[n, x], {n, {4}}]; 
c[n_, x_] := (1/n) Sum[s[m, x], {m, 0, n - 1}]
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], partialsums[x], c[{4}, x]}], {x, -Pi, Pi},
PlotLegends -> {"f(x)=x", "Fourier, 4 terms", "Cesaro, 4 terms"}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Dashed, Thickness[0.006]}, {Red,Thickness[0.006]}}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Coding Issue:**

You can try to use `DiscretePlot` for the above expression out of the box in *Mathematica*!

```
DiscretePlot[
Evaluate@(-((Sqrt[2] FresnelS[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n]])/
    n^(3/2)) - (Sqrt[2] FresnelS[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Abs[n]]])/
  Abs[n]^(3/2) + (2 Sin[n π])/n + (2 Sin[π Abs[n]])/
  Abs[n])/(2 Sqrt[π]), {n, 1, 150}]
```

[image: DiscretePlot result]

Your code has minor typos! Before plotting always better to check what your functions are returning given an argument then you can spot the mistake in your code.

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[Abs[Mod[x, 2 π, -π]]];
s[k_, x_] := Sum[(2 - 2 Cos[n π] - n π Sin[n π])/(n^2 π) Cos[n x], {n, 1, k}]
partialsums[x_] = First @ Table[N @ s[n, x], {n, {4}}];
c[n_, x_] := Sum[s[m, x], {m, 0, n - 1}]/n;
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], partialsums[x], c[4, x]}], {x, -π, π},
PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Dashed, Thickness[0.006]}, {Red,Thickness[0.006]}}]
```

[image: function with partial sums and Cesàro means]

**Actual Answer:**

*Definition:* Let ${a_n}_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of real (or possibly complex numbers).
The  *Cesàro mean* of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$
with
$$\begin{equation}
b_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i.
\end{equation}$$

*Code:*
Define the partial sum and the Cesàro mean to take only `Integer` argument!

```
f[x_] := N @ Sqrt[Abs[Mod[x, 2 π, -π]]]; 
part[k_?IntegerQ] := Total[(N @ f[#]) & /@ Range[0, k]];
cesaro[k_?IntegerQ] := part[k]/(k + 1);
```

*Testing:* Check functions only evaluate for `Integer` argument.

```
Evaluate @ {f[k], part[k], cesaro[k]} /. k -> 2
```

> ```
> {1.41421, 2.41421, 0.804738}
> ```

Now plotting what you want!

```
DiscretePlot[Evaluate @ {f[k], cesaro[k]}, {k, 1, 50}, Frame -> True, 
PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[Medium]}, {Blue, Dashed}}, Joined -> {False, True}]
```

[image: DiscretePlot of Cesàro means]

Comment: I had modified my post above. I am not trying to graph this function but I am trying to graph this in another terms. Do look at my code above.

Comment: Oops! I see. I think I had a mistake in my post as I just copy and paste. The s[k_, x_] part is wrong. This is one of my tryout for the function Pi/2 - Abs[x] with its correspondence s[k_, x_] but for my actual Sqrt[Abs[Mod[x, 2 Pi, -Pi]]] I can't find its partial sums due to this Fresnel function.

Comment: So discreteplot is my only choice after all in order for me to graph these type of functions. I am trying to plot like the second diagram you had posted above but to no avail. Thanks Platomaniac. You had solve a lot of my queries with Mathematica.

Comment: @Sandra you can use many other plotting functions too. But `DiscretePlot` can take your expression as it is.